# z3 context reset API

Tags: z3

I want to reset the context in z3, similarly to what I do in yices: `void yices_reset (yices_context ctx)`
Is there an equivalent command for z3? Currently I use `Z3_del_context(ctx);` but I am not sure it is the most efficient way. Should I use the push/pop context commands, or is there another method?

Answer (score 4):

`Z3_del_context(ctx)` is an option. However, in your question, you mention push/pop. So, it seems you actually want to reset just the set of assertions. If that is the case, I suggest you start using `Z3_solver` objects. We can create many different `Z3_solver` objects in a `Z3_context` object. The main advantage is they may share declarations, formulas, expressions, etc. BTW, Z3 comes with a C++ wrapper (`z3++.h`) that is much easier to use them the C API. Here is a C++ example using multiple solver objects. BTW, you can use multiple solver objects at the same time.

```
context c;
expr x = c.int_const("x");
expr y = c.int_const("y");
{
   solver s(c);

   s.add(x >= 1);
   s.add(y < x + 3);
   std::cout << s.check() << "\n";

   model m = s.get_model();
   std::cout << m << "\n";
   // solver object c will be destroyed at this point
}
{
   // creating a new solver object
   solver s2(c);
   s2.add(x > y + 1);
   std::cout << s2.check() << "\n";
}
```

***EDIT***: Solver objects also have a `reset` method. It erases all assertions asserted in a given solver.

Comment: Does reset in solver object reset the context as well in z3py?